# Google Distance Matrix JSON shortest path (PHP)

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3, matrix, distance

A client requested me to calculate the distance from a certain address to a fixed address. I made a PHP script utilizing the Google Distance Matrix API to calculate the distance. However, this does not give me the shortest distance. It seems to just give whatever Google thinks is best. For example, my script returns 11.7 kilometers between 2 addresses while Google Maps gives these results:

- 8.7km
- 14km
- 13.8km

As you can see, 8.7km is a pretty significant difference from 11.7km.

I would consider other options than the Google Distance Matrix API.

My script: (in a nutshell)

```
if ($this->getVar('to', false) && $this->getVar('to', false) != '') {
    $to = urlencode(urldecode($this->getVar('to', false)));
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Etterbeeksesteenweg+180+Brussel&destinations='.$to.'&mode=driving&language=nl-BE&sensor=false';
    $this->view->response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
}
```

I tried to add `&alternatives=true`, but with no success.

Comment: why don't you give us the destination string or geo code to test it ourselves?

Comment: Could you clarify, you've been asked to calculate the distance, and then you talk about travelling time. By distance, you mean = km? minutes? What's your goal?

Comment: I'm sorry that I was unclear. The travelling time has nothing to do with it. The result should be the shortest distance in km. These distances were acquired with the origin "kievitwijk 28, helchteren" and the destination "bomerstraat 18, peer". The URL to the result would be http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=kievitwijk+28+helchteren&destinations=bomerstraat+18+peer&mode=driving&language=nl-BE&sensor=false

Comment: Ah, and the API is providing the wrong shortest distance in what way- is it actually geographically incorrect? Or is it not as the crow flies etc?

Comment: What I was trying to get to- I suspect the google distance API is good if you want the best travelling time, but that of course bares little resemblance to the as-the-crow flies. What would be the issue with using their GeoCoding API and getting the absolute distance between the two places from that.

Comment: If you are only looking for a single distance/route perhaps use the [DirectionsService](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=kievitwijk%2028,%20helchteren&addr2=bomerstraat%2018,%20peer&geocode=1&geocode=2), that gives me the 11.7km. Which is what [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=kievitwijk+28,+helchteren&daddr=bomerstraat+18,+peer&hl=en&sll=51.130875,5.446849&sspn=0.007446,0.021136&geocode=FdZCCwMdiRRSACmBZBGIuyjBRzEjSbfeOsa1MA%3BFfsxDAMdwRxTACm7FriFjCnBRzEYWF2Qg7PTKA&mra=ls&t=m&z=12) gives me.

Comment: When you use the actual Google Maps, it gives 3 suggested routes. One of these three routes is 9km, the others are 13.6km and 13.7km. I do not need the distance as the crow flies, but the actual shortest driving distance. However, through the API, I don't get the shortest distance (i.e. 9km), but I get 11.7km. What my client needs is not 11.7km, but 9km. Is this possible in any way? I hope I was clear enough now.

Comment: The 9.0 km result is returned if you use the provideRouteAlternatives option in the directions request: [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=kievitwijk%2028,%20helchteren&addr2=bomerstraat%2018,%20peer&geocode=1&geocode=2&alternatives=yes)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The DistanceMatrixService(and the DirectionsService too) usually will not return the **shortest** route, they will return the **fastest** route.

Use the DirectionsService instead with an additional parameter `alternatives` set to true:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=bomerstraat%2018,%20peer&destination=kievitwijk%2028,%20helchteren&alternatives=true&sensor=false

When you add the `alternatives`-parameter you also get alternative routes, when you inspect the returned result you will see that it also contains the 9km-route. But this route has a duration of 17 minutes, while the suggested (longer) route has a duration of 16 minutes, that's why the longer route is the suggested route.

So fetch the shortest route out of the returned routes.

Example:

```
<?php
  //request the directions
$routes=json_decode(file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=bomerstraat%2018,%20peer&destination=kievitwijk%2028,%20helchteren&alternatives=true&sensor=false'))->routes;

  //sort the routes based on the distance
usort($routes,create_function('$a,$b','return intval($a->legs[0]->distance->value) - intval($b->legs[0]->distance->value);'));

 //print the shortest distance
echo $routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->text;//returns 9.0 km
?>
```

**Note:** you may get different results on google-maps and from the service, because google-maps will take into account the current traffic-situation, but the service will not (except when you have a business-license)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.

My client wanted two data points. Shortest route, and shortest distance 'as the crow flies'.

I still use the distancematrix for 'quickest' route as I have found this to be very accurate taking local data and even traffic into account.

I calculated the direct point to point distance using math on the lat long of the two addresses - http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

There can be issues here too though. In one of my cases the distancematrix took a route over a harbour bridge showing a much greater distance than the lat long calc did, which of course was direct over water.

One other little warning: There is a limit to the number of calls any IP can make to the Google Maps API. I moved a large portion of the hits to the API in JavaScript, using the end clients quota rather than that of the server - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple legs, above solution won't work. So, here my version of alternative.

```
public function get_shortest_route($routes)
{
    if(!$routes){
        return null;
    }

    $shortest_route = $routes[0];
    foreach($routes as $index => $route){

        if(!isset($routes[$index+1])){
            break;
        }

        $totalDistance1 = 0;
        foreach($route->legs as $leg){
            $totalDistance1 += $leg->distance->value;
        }

        $totalDistance2 = 0;
        foreach($route[$index+1]->legs as $leg){
            $totalDistance2 += $leg->distance->value;
        }

        $shortest_route = $totalDistance1 < $totalDistance2 ? $route : $routes[$index+1];

    }

    return $shortest_route;
}
```